# Different versions of JBoss on the same host

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x

I have JBoss 4 installed on my PC to directory C:\JBoss4
And environment variable JBOSS_HOME set to this directory:

```
JBOSS_HOME=C:\JBoss4
```

I need to install JBoss 5.1 on the same PC.
I installed it into C:\JBoss51
In order to start JBoss 5.1 on the same host where JBoss 4 was already started, I need to redefine properties **jboss.home.dir, jboss.home.url, jboss.service.binding.set**:

```
C:\JBoss51\bin\run.sh -Djboss.home.dir=C:/JBoss51 \
                      -Djboss.home.url=file:/C:/JBoss51 \
                      -Djboss.service.binding.set=ports-01
```

But in **C:\JBoss51\bin\run.sh** I can see following code:

```
…
if [ "x$JBOSS_HOME" = "x" ]; then
    # get the full path (without any relative bits)
    JBOSS_HOME=`cd $DIRNAME/..; pwd`
fi
export JBOSS_HOME
…
runjar="$JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.jar"
JBOSS_BOOT_CLASSPATH="$runjar"
```

And this code does not depend either on **jboss.home.dir** or on **jboss.home.dir**.
So when I start JBoss 5.1 script will use jar files from JBoss 4.3?
Is it correct?
Should I redefine environment variable JAVA_HOME when I start JBoss 5.1?
In this case script will use correct jar files.
Or if I redefined properties **jboss.home.dir, jboss.home.url** then JBoss will not use any variables set in run.sh?

***How does it works?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is not to set the `JBOSS_HOME` environment variable at all. If you call `run.bat` without the variable being set, then the script will set it to its own JBoss directory. Explicitly setting it allows you to override where JBoss looks for things, but then you have to manage it yourself, and you get into a mess.

So remove the variable, and let JBoss take care of its own directories.

Comment: I cannot remove JBOSS_HOME.
On production environment JBoss 4 used by other products.
And they explicitly set JBOSS_HOME.

But I need to use JBoss 5.
I see that two different instances of JBoss works without problems. But I am not shure that my JBoss do not use jar files from installation of JBoss 4.

Comment: In that case, change the value of `JBOSS_HOME` before you run JBoss 5. You should be able to change it locally within the script that calls JBoss's `run.bat`

Comment: Yes - I can to do it. But I want to know - should I to do it or changing of jboss.home.dir/jboss.home.dir properties will be enough?

Comment: @Vladimir: Changing `JBOSS_HOME` is easier - don't mess with the individual system properties unless you really need to

Comment: I do not understand - why there are jboss.home.dir,  jboss.home.url properties if we can just redefine JBOSS_HOME or start jboss from directory where JBoss was installed?

Comment: @Vladimir: Because some users want to change the position of the log dir etc, relative to `JBOSS_HOME`. You don't need to, so don't mess with those properties, just change `JBOSS_HOME`.

Comment: If someone would like to change location of log directory or directory with configuration(default, web, etc) he should change swp.jboss.deploy.url and jboss.server.base.dir/jboss.server.base.url.
It does not depend on JBOSS_HOME.

Comment: OK, I'm rapidly losing interest in this question... take it or leave it, chap.

Answer (score 1):

in my community 7 version i can edit the /bin/standalone.conf.bat and in your case set the variable like this:

```
set "JBOSS_HOME=C:\JBoss51"
```

right after this:

```
if not "x%JAVA_OPTS%" == "x" (
  echo "JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: %JAVA_OPTS%"
  goto JAVA_OPTS_SET
)
```

This makes to load the JBOSS_HOME from the conf. and not from the environment variable, hope this can be helpfull!

Answer (score 0):

Had this same problem with wildfly 8. I had another JBOSS instance using the JBOSS_HOME environment variable. I added the "set "JBOSS_HOME=.." as specified above and it worked.